# How to zoom in,zoom out ,drag & drop and rotate an image view in android?

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, zooming, pinchzoom

if any have idea to pinch zoom,zoom in ,zoom out ,rotation(left & right),drag & drop for imageview,please help me if any one have idea ,thanks in advance

Comment: please post some code and what you have tried?

Comment: Use onTouchListener of Imageview

Comment: -1 Its a Q/A Site not "Give Definition,Get Example" - Put here what you tried and tell where you got problems.

Comment: A complete tutorial check this [link](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/how-to-use-multi-touch-in-android-2-part-6-implementing-the-pinch-zoom-gesture/1847) & Before asking question you should try yourself first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/319401/Simple-Gestures-on-Android) an article that discusses multi-touch gestures on Android from a beginners perspective. It demonstrates an approach that allows for "standard" gestures such as slide-to-move and pinch-to-zoom but also endevours to go beyond those and attempt turn-to-rotate. The source is attached too, and [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Se7Si9VwKYY) a demo showing some features that was developed in this article

Also [here](https://github.com/jasonpolites/gesture-imageview/blob/master/main/src/com/polites/android/GestureImageView.java) a custom ImageView that uses some gesture features you can use it in your code

Comment: it is working fine,pinch rotation is also working,but i want to rotate an image using button like(left,right) when i click left button i want to rotate (zoom)image to left size and right button must be rotate to right size.if u have idea help me.